# C# Ping crashes entire program

Tags: c#, winforms, ping

I am building a C# windows form app that pings multiple computers by name, which the user can specify.

I am using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class and the SendAsync method, with a method to handle the result.

The issue I am having occurs when the user specifies a computer name which does not exist. Rather than Ping returning an error to my callback method, however, I get a TargetInvocationException at Application.Run(new Form()) (the main method of the entire form). I have tried surrounding relevant code with try/catch but they never seem to catch the exception

Here is relevant code for ping:

```
Ping p = null;
try
{
    p = new Ping();
    p.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler (updateUI);
    p.SendAsync(computername, 10, computername);
}
    catch (Exception)
{
    ((IDisposable)p).Dispose();
    MessageBox.Show("Ping Failed...");
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the StackTrace of the InnerException of the TargetInvocationException to find out where the exception comes from.

Comment: Or try using Send instead on a seperate thread

Comment: Check your PingCompletedEventHandler. You're doing this async, so not everything occurs inside your try catch block. Your event will spawn separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the e.Error property first in your PingCompleted event handler.  Trying to use the other properties when it is not null is a guaranteed kaboom.  From the PingCompletedEventArgs.Error property documentation in MSDN:

> If an exception is raised during an asynchronous operation, the class will assign the exception to the Error property. The client application's event-handler delegate should check the Error property before accessing any properties in a class derived from AsyncCompletedEventArgs; otherwise, the property will raise a **TargetInvocationException** with its InnerException property holding a reference to Error.

Answer (score -1):

Well since your exception handler is not getting hit, it must be in the other part of your code where the error is occuring.

Comment: SendAsync can throw an exception outside the try/catch block

Comment: It doesn't matter how hard you try to get someone to think for themselves.. someone else always has to ruin the ending.